# How to append regular text to a TextBlock that already has a Binding to its text property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, microsoft-metro

I have a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="someText" Text="{Binding ElementName=theList, Path=SelectedItem.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

And as you can see, it is bound to another element's selected item. Now, let's just say that, for example, the selected item says "Hello, ". And I want to append my name to it (in XAML, not code-behind), so that it reads like: "Hello, Arrow.". How can I do this?

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="someText" TextWrapping="NoWrap">             
   <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=theList, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
   <Run Text=" Arrow." />
</TextBlock>
```

XAML solutions not available yet on Metro XAML:

You can use [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx):

```
<TextBlock x:Name="someText" Text="{Binding ElementName=theList, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}{0} Arrow.}" />
```

Also you can use MultiBinding and [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx):

```
<TextBlock>
     <TextBlock.Text>
          <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} Arrow.">
               <Binding ElementName="theList" Path="SelectedItem.Name" />                    
          </MultiBinding>
     </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: As for StringFormat: `The Property 'StringFormat' was not found in type Binding.` And `MultiBinding is not supported in a Windows Metro style project.`

Comment: A `TextBlock` with multiple `Run`s is definitely the way to go for this.

Answer (score 3):

With this configuration the only thing you could do is have that text in the selected item. So, what I would recommend is something more along these lines:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock x:Name="someText"
        Text="{Binding ElementName=theList,
                       Path=SelectedItem.Name,
                       Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="suffixText"/>
</StackPanel>
```

With this configuration you can provide the `suffixText` any way you want and get the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you need create a MultiValueConverter for this which concatenates two strings. You can pass those strings from xaml to converter. more details see [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328978/Introduction-to-multi-binding-and-multi-value-conv)